# node.js request | sometimes unexpected token error sometimes not

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, syntax, request

I've got a for loop that calls a weather api 27 times (27 different coordinates).

```
var input = {
            query: coords[1] + ',' + coords[0] ,
            format: 'JSON',
            fx: ''
          };
var url = _PremiumApiBaseURL + "marine.ashx?q=" + input.query + "&format=" + input.format + "&fx=" + input.fx + "&key=" + _PremiumApiKey;    
request(url,function (err, resp, body){
            body = JSON.parse(body);
```

The returned body is string type.
The thing is that when doing the JSON.parse sometimes i get the error shown below and sometimes not. Sometimes it does 3 ok and then throws the error, sometimes 7, sometimes just 1 or sometimes does the 27 ok and throws no error. I can't see where is the problem as the 27 returned data objects are always the same.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/Users/nofunat88/Documents/test/nodejs-express-ajax-test/borrar_final.js:111:29)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/nofunat88/Documents/test/nodejs-express-ajax-test/node_modules/request/request.js:129:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/nofunat88/Documents/test/nodejs-express-ajax-test/node_modules/request/request.js:873:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/nofunat88/Documents/test/nodejs-express-ajax-test/node_modules/request/request.js:824:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Regards,

Comment: Hey Aitor, I am facing the same error, but having error check not solving this problem. I don't know how its intermittent.do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Sorry, i solved that way, maybe you should open your own thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall check if error occurred during the request, and then - parse the body.

```
request(url,function (err, resp, body){
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    body = JSON.parse(body); 
                }
```

Comment: i don't really understand why but after adding the check for errors it doesn't show any syntax errors anymore!